# How to sort a mongodb query result in ascending order of age, without a createdAt field? (new to old)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

When you do a mongodb query, you normally get the results in descending order of age(old to new). How can I get it in the ascending order?

I know that I can save the createdAt timestamp and do a

```
  .sort({createdAt:-1})
```

on the query to do this, but saving the cretedAt timestamp seperately when the information is already present in _id seems like overkill.

Is there a way to get the results in the ascending order of age (new to old) without using a createdAt timestamp?

Comment: What do you mean "information is already present in _id"? And what is the problem with saving a createdAt property on each document? You could order by the _id property, but it's not as clean as having a readable date. Without date fields you're going to have a difficult time doing temporal-driven queries.

Answer (score 1):

timestamp is already stored in `_id` field. So if you want to sort documents from new to old. You can do it in the following way -

`sort({_id:-1})`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the **natural order** which reflects insertion order of documents.

Consider the following query :

```
db.trees.insert( { _id: 1, name: "oak"} )
db.trees.insert( { _id: 2, name: "chestnut"} )
db.trees.insert( { _id: 3, name: "maple"} )
db.trees.insert( { _id: 4, name: "birch"} )
```

The following query returns the documents in the natural order :

```
db.trees.find().sort( { $natural: 1 } )
```

```
[
 { "_id" : 1, "name" : "oak"}
 { "_id" : 2, "name" : "chestnut"}
 { "_id" : 3, "name" : "maple"}
 { "_id" : 4, "name" : "birch"}
]
```

However remove operations free up space which are then taken up by newly inserted documents then, natural order of documents will not reflect insertion order.